# Get the type of class to use in generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am trying to make a method that accepts any model to be bound to a Json response but I can't work out how to dynamically insert the type of class model into the generic parameter.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    public static async Task<object> DoPost(string url, FormUrlEncodedContent formEnc, object model)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, formEnc))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var modelType = model.GetType();
            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<modelType>(result);

            return model;
        }
    }
```

How do I get the proper representation of type into `modelType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply changed to a Generic such as below. Then your Generic can be easily deserialized out.

```
public static async Task<T> DoPost<T>(string url, FormUrlEncodedContent formEnc)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, formEnc))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
    }
}
```

Now this can be called with any type of `model` as the generic parameter. This can be called now just passing in the Generic paramter as `T` such as:

```
 var user = DoPost<User>(url, formEnc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` to populate the instance directly :

```
var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
model = JsonConvert.PopulateObject(result, model);

return model;
```